# How do I create a field using ng-if in a dynamic list (index included)?

Tags: angularjs, list, dynamic, field

I've used this method a thousand times to create a "please describe" field when the "other" option is selected, but it is not working when it is part of a dynamic list. Something about the addition of the index is making it not work. How can I make this work in a dynamic list?

Normally, I would try one of these:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="discrepancy_resolution_other_{{$index}}" ng-true-value="'Checked'" ng-false-value="'delete'"> Other
    </label>
    <label ng-if="model.discrepancy_resolution_other_{{$index}} === 'Checked'">
        <input type="text" name="discrepancy_resolution_other_content" placeholder="Please describe" required="true">
    </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="discrepancy_resolution_other_{{$index}}" ng-true-value="'Checked'" ng-false-value="'delete'"> Other
    </label>
    <label ng-if="model[discrepancy_resolution_other_{{$index}}] === 'Checked'">
        <input type="text" name="discrepancy_resolution_other_content_{{$index}}" placeholder="Please describe" required="true">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include code, or at least the "method" you mention.

Comment: He included markup, and I keep editing it to fix it, but he keeps overwriting my edits with jacked up markdown.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot work:

```
ng-if="model.discrepancy_resolution_other_{{$index}} === 'Checked'"
```

Remember simply that you cannot use interpolations `{{}}` within a `ng-if` (or `ng-show`) expression. If your variable is named `discrepancy_resolution_other_3` for instance, you could solve your problem doing:

```
ng-if="getThing(model, $index) === 'Checked'"
```

And then in your controller implement getThing:

```
$scope.getThing = function(model, index) {
  if (index === 3) {
    return model.discrepancy_resolution_other_3;
  }
  // etc...
}
```

However it would be easier to put your variables into an array `$scope.model.myArray` so you could directly access it from the HTML:

```
ng-if="model.myArray[$index] === 'Checked'"
```